# How to post a SQS event from karate

Tags: spring-boot, karate, amazon-sqs

In karate instead of testing an API endpoint, I want to post an event to SQS and test it. Is there any recommended way to do it via JAVA / JAVASCRIPT / SQS POST API? Any available resources or info could help.